# understanding time complexity of a set and a map

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, set, hashtable

Is the time complexity when it comes to maps AND sets the same for operations like insertion, removal, search ? I read somewhere that underlying structure is a hash table meaning that time would be constant o(1) ? is that always the case ?

Answer (score 0):

`Map` and `Set` are just interfaces and say nothign about time complexity. Java SE provides different implementations (e.g. `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, ...) that are based on different concepts and hence have different strengths and weaknesses concerning time complexity. Have a look at JavaDoc of every implementation, there the time complexity is explained for all important operations/methods!

Comment: One thing to note is that a `HashSet` _is a_ `HashMap` and a `TreeSet` _is a_ `TreeMap`.